# jenkins windows agent not getting the full profile

Tags: jenkins

I am facing an peculiar problem with my windows jenkins agent. I have started the agent from a JNLP file. Doing a build in the agent which write some log to file in shared path.

When i am starting the agent, by double clicking on jnlp file, the build goes well as the build is able to write data to the shared path.

But, then i am making the jnlp run as a service and doing build, the build is not able to write to the shared path.  Checked with team about the shared path and the shared path has full access.

One thing i marked, jenkins build is not getting all the environment variables when i am running it as a service.

Has any one faced this issue or have any idea to resolve it.

Thanks,
Tarakant

Comment: Have you tried configuring the service to start using the same user as you log in manually?

Comment: @stara You're probably running Windows service as "Local System". If you're not getting usual environment variables, in service properties set yourself in "Log on" tab.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. I have done both the thing and still having the same issue. I thought may be i am trying to write to shared path, so the issue is. I tried local path in the windows machine and still getting the same issue. It is not able to write to to the local file too when it starts running as a service. When manually i start the agent from JNLP, it works, able to write to both local and shared path.